# How can I change the forecolor of a NSMutableAtrributedString Link in addAttribute

Tags: nsattributedstring

I have an issue with the following code returning a white foreground color for the hyperlink. Now because this the view has a white background the hyperlinked part of the string doesn't appear due to white on white

Here is the code to make the hyperlink. Just an extension on NSAttribiutedString

```
extension NSAttributedString {

  static func makeHyperlink(for path: String, in string: String, as substring: String) -> 
NSAttributedString {

    let nsString = NSString(string: string)
    let substringRange = nsString.range(of: substring)

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)

    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: path, range: substringRange)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: substringRange)
    return attributedString

  }

}
```

basically it send in the String of the UITextView, Path to link to, and the substring I want to apply the link to. Here is how I am calling it

googleTextViewLink.Text = "Google It"

```
let googlePath = "http://www.google.com/search?q=\(term.Description)"
let text = googleTextViewLink.text ?? ""
let attributedString  = NSAttributedString.makeHyperlink(for: googlePath, in: text, as: "Google")
googleTextViewLink.attributedText = attributedString
```

I cant seem to see where the link is returned as white as I explicitly change its forecolour to UIColor.red in the extension?

Comment: Why not using `linkTextAttributes` of `UITextView`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618632-linktextattributes

Comment: Tried that to no avail.   self.googleTextViewLink.linkTextAttributes = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
      ].  still comes out with white forecolor for teh link